# ODBC Data Source can't find MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to add the MySQL driver data source, but when I click on the add option, it doesn't list the driver in 32-bit mode, but only in 64-bit mode, but the thing is I need the 32-bit version (I'm running the newest stable ODBC version).

Here is the driver listed just fine in 64-bit mode:
[image]

In 33-bit mode I get a bunch of "random" drivers listed, but not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try to use the 5.3.10 driver. It has a 32 bit version.

Comment: Yes, that was the desired solution.